# Problem code and show comments

Tags: comments, shortcode

**I use this code in shortcode for show posts :**

```
<?php
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 

$imagen = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), "medium");
$ruta_imagen = $imagen[0];
if ($ruta_imagen!="")
{
$ruta_img="<a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'><img src='".$ruta_imagen."' width='".$img_width."' height='".$img_height."' class='image_car'></a>";
}
echo $ruta_img;

endwhile;
?>
```

This code works perfect inside the code for create the shortcode , but the problem it´s if i use the shortcode and put active the comments for ones post or page , the form and comments no show

I don´t understand what have bada this code for no let show the comments , if i don´t use this shortcode the comments show other time and the form

Please if you can tell me which it´s the problem perfect for me

Thank´s , regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very hard to understand but I think that you might need to put [`wp_reset_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) or [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after your Loop (after `endwhile;`) to to reset the loop and/or the `$post` variable.

Comment: Yesssssssssss works !!!!!!!!!!